# JS - Find out the visible percentage of an obscured DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, css, intersection

**Edit** The following HTML and CSS are just an **example**, the real use-case involves a complex DOM, and should be generic enough to work on different webpages.  Only valid assumption is that all elements are rectangular.

---

Given the following:

HTML

```
<div class="a" id="a">
A
</div>
<div class="b">
B
</div>
<div class="c">
  C
  <div class="d">
  D
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.a,.b,.c,.d{
  border: solid 1px black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-family: arial;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.a{
  width:300px;
  height:250px;
  top:30px;
  left:20px;
  background:green;
}

.b{
  width:300px;
  height:145px;
  top:10px;
  left:20px;
  background:blue;
}
.c{
  width:150px;
  height:300px;
  top:30px;
  left:60px;
  background:red;
}
.d{
  margin:10px;
  background:yellow;
  width:100px;
  height:200px
}
```

produces the following result:
[image]

---

I'm trying to detect the percentage of the "A" DIV that is not obscured by other elements, IE: 25% in the given example.

I've written the following JS ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/apctgroq/)) that scans the rect area of the "A" DIV and collects the obscuring elements.

```
let el = document.getElementById("a");
let rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
let right = rect.x + rect.width;
let bottom = rect.y + rect.height;
let elements = [];
for (let i = rect.x; i < right; i += 10) {
  for (let j = rect.y; j < bottom; j += 10) {
    let sampled = document.elementFromPoint(i, j);
    if (sampled && sampled !== el && elements.indexOf(sampled) === -1) {
      elements.push(sampled);
    }
  }
}
```

Now I'm trying to find the most efficient way to do the calculations. I tried another approach of scanning the rect pixel by pixel and count all pixels that are not part of the main DIV, however this approach appeared to be slow for an accepted solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
After doing some research, I'm starting to think I will need the sweep-line algorithm, still not exactly sure how to modify the code to fit my problem.

**Update 2**
When using `pointer-events: none;`, the `document.elementFromPoint` approach will not work, so I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: Are all objects rectangular?

Comment: Would it be acceptably fast to iterate over all DOM elements (instead of over all pixels)? About how many DOM elements are there?

Comment: The DOM could be with many elements. All objects are rect

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Intersection Observer` to get the visible percentage of an element within a parent..

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

It’s experimental though!

Comment: Very interesting, I'll look into it

Comment: Nice, however it does not solve my issue, because you still need to select the elements to check the intersection with

Answer (score 0):

I think i would try different approach.

Assumptions:

1. assuming all elements are rectangles
2. <s>assuming all elements have `z-index` higher than `A`</s>

I would:

1. get context element rectangle (that is, the DOM element that is the first parent of both: `A` element and all of those that might obscure `A`)
2. list all its children that could obscure A (so, all but `A`)
3. get bounding rectangle for each of them
4. sort those that have `z-index` higher than `A` element by: top, right, bottom & left coordinate
5. once you have top,right,bottom,left - most coordinates of obscuring elements you can subtract those from your `A` rectangle coordinates and calculate area

for many potentially obscuring elements you can further optimize by removing sorting step but instead, keep track of top/right/bottom/left -most coordinates as you iterate obscuring elements and update them if currently iterated one is more in either direction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, please see my edits. Any DOM element on the page could be blocking the main element. and you assumptions are not valid.

Comment: please be precise. which assumption in particular is not valid? asking because, if all elements might potentially obscure `A` that only means that context element is `body`. So, what exactly is not valid?

Comment: I assume OP means assumption 1

Comment: i don't think so. from all he said, it sounds like he works with rectangles only.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over *all* dom elements and collect the obscuring ones. This would give a complexity of `O(n)` where n = number of elements instead of `O(x * y)` where `x` and `y` are the pixel width and height of the div, respectively.

```
let el = document.getElementById("a");
let rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
let right = rect.x + rect.width;
let bottom = rect.y + rect.height;
let baseDepth = parseFloat(el.style.zIndex);
if (baseDepth === NaN) {
  baseDepth = 0;
}
let all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
let obscuringElements = [];
for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
    let sample = all[i];
    if (sample !== el && elements.indexOf(sample) === -1) {
      let subRect = sample.getBoundingClientRect();
      if (subRect.x <= right && subRect.x + subRect.width >= rect.x
        && subRect.y <= bottom && subRect.y + subRect.height >= rect.y) {
          obscuringElements.push(sample);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use the bounding rects of `obscuringElements` to figure out how much of `el` is visible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think your solution will be slow when DOM is large, and the obscuring elements are in part obscuring each other, and you need to figure out the real area that they obscure.

Comment: Either you're going to need to go element-by-element or pixel-by-pixel. In 99% of cases element-by-element is going to be faster. `document.elementFromPoint(i, j);` needs to cycle through elements anyway.

Comment: I agree, but this does not solve the calculation of the overlapping obscuring elements. for example C,D in the above example

Comment: Oh you can totally account for that here, you have all the information you need. Just remove area from the initial area, you can't remove the same area twice.

Comment: Not ver efficient, I'll need to check every rect with every rect or try to implement something like this: https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-part1/lecture/mNiwq/rectangle-intersection

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking your initial solution, the idea was to remove the pointer-events style while using the `elementFromPoint` method.

```
function addCSS(){
    let style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = '* {pointer-events: all !important;}';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);

    Array.prototype.filter.call(document.querySelectorAll("[style]"),(node)=>{
      return node.style.pointerEvents;
    }).forEach((node)=>{
      node.style.pointerEvents = "all";
    })
}
```

see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rrgc95r1/2/)